# PHP exec doesn't return output of external program

Tags: php, windows, exec

I've the following program:

```
function execute_query($ip, $username, $password, $query){
    $runCMD ="python run_query.py " . escapeshellarg($ip). " ". escapeshellarg($username) . " " . escapeshellarg($password)
        .  ' ' . escapeshellarg($query);
    $output = [];
    exec ($runCMD, $output);
    print_r ($output);
    //return (implode("\n", $output));
}
```

However the array $output is always empty, the program is returning the result correctly, when executed manually from CMD. I've no idea what to do. I tried so many things that I even don't recall all of them. Here are a few:

```
1.I disable UAC
2.I tried using shell_exec
3.I tried appending powershell in front of the command 'powershell' . $runCmd
4.I tried appending '2>&1' at the end of the command
5.I tried using proc_open, to manually open cmd.exe and execute the command
```

Any other ideas what I may do, or at least how to continue troubleshooting. Using Linux is not an option
It seems like stderr is working. Also i tried printing 'asd' from the python script and it's working.
The output from the python script is WMI query, it may contain \n, \r and \t

Here is the python script:

```
from subprocess import check_output
import sys

def run_query(ip, username, password, query):
    runCMD = "query.exe " + username + " " + password + ' "' + query + '" ' + ip + ''
    results = check_output(runCMD).decode("utf-8")
    results = results.split("\n")
    for result in results:  
        if not result.startswith("__"):
            print(result)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_query(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
```

UPDATE 1 
query.exe is a program, which returns filtered result from WMI query, passed as argument. No idea what's inside but it's working as expected. I also tried running query.exe from the php script, the same thing no output.
  UPDATE 2 
 I'm using php 7.1, tried php 5.6 without luck.
UPDATE 3 
When I try to change the string into byte array in python I get this output when the script is manually runned:

```
bytearray(b'The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)\r')
bytearray(b'')
```

, but the php script returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bytearray(b'')
)
```

UPDATE 4

f*** it I'm switching the whole project to python

Comment: You should probably try this with an absolute path and add some debugging to your python script to verify it is being invoked in the first place.

Comment: I also tried using absolute path, forgot to mention it. I will add now a few lines in the python script

Comment: It seems that the python script is being called. Also if i try to print 'asd' from the python script, it's being captured by the PHP application.

Comment: So your script outputs to stderr? This isn't mentioned in your question.

Comment: No it's actually logging into file. Currently I made a mistake, in the python script and it printed it. I didn't know that stderr works by now

Comment: Ok it's really not clear what you're asking. What output from the python program do you expect to be returned to php? Can you edit your question with the relevant details?

Comment: We'd need to see the content of the python script to help more. It's possible that run_queries.py is completing without actually sending any data to stdout.

Comment: Added all the needed information

Comment: So when you add a debugging print, it shows up in php? Could it be your python script doesn't have the correct path when invoked from php? You should add debug statements for that as well. Or much simpler, just call the program from php. Calling a python script that that then calls yet another external program seems like a pointless and fragile layer of complexity

Comment: As I noted running the program from PHP doesn't return any output as well. When I add print('test') in the python script it's being captured by the php script.

Comment: That would still be consistent with a path issue in the PHP case.

Comment: Check the update, since it's unreadable when typed here.

Comment: Maybe you should leave the processing of the output to the php side. Do you know it's utf-8 to begin with? Additionally, print_r might not be the best way to determine what's actually in the array.

Comment: I'm not sure about the encoding of the output, I tried to encode it as latin-1 in python. As I said if I run query.exe, I still don't get any result. At least the python script is getting the result correctly. I tried using var_dump the same result.

Comment: Even stranger thing happends. Currently the script is saving the output in file. When the script is executed from php, nothing is written in the file, however test is still printed. On other hand if the script is executed manually the result is written in the file